# error using fgets()

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

Hi can someone help me with this error?
The errors I'm getting are:

```
Building target: Programming Cpt220
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `g++  -o "Programming Cpt220"  ./fgets()exampleFromTheNet.o   '
make: *** [Programming Cpt220] Error 2
g++  -o "Programming Cpt220"  ./fgets()exampleFromTheNet.o
```

I'm not sure why ist is asking for g++ -o
I'm using eclipse on Mac.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define  MAX_LEN  100

int main(void)
{
   FILE *stream;
   char line[MAX_LEN], *result;

   stream = fopen("myfile.dat","r");

   if ((result = fgets(line,MAX_LEN,stream)) != NULL)
       printf("The string is %s\n", result);

   if (fclose(stream))
       printf("fclose error\n");


}
```

Comment: It sounds like whatever is managing your build process is totally broken; this is total nonsense: `g++  -o "Programming Cpt220"  ./fgets()exampleFromTheNet.o`

Comment: Erm, did you put brackets into your source file's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is expecting there to be a "()" in your filename, which is killing the shell script that you are running.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `()` from the filename of your C file.

i.e. `fgets()exampleFromTheNet.c` -> `fgetsExampleFromTheNet.c`

`()` has a special meaning in `bash` and other shells. Hence it is recommended to avoid having any special characters in filenames.

Comment: Ok I have removed the brackets and it runs.